# In ms Access is there any way to combine search boxes and output the the sum of both not just the union of the two

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Fairly new to access and trying to get my head around doing things in code for the first time and so I'm sure there must be a really simple solution to what I'm attempting but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

At the moment I have a form with 2 search boxes, one outputting the current names for the 'Managers' and the other outputting all names that any manager has had previously so an 'Alias' search. when a manager is clicked then it launches the manager form and shows a whole host of information about it and when an alias is clicked the current manager is opened. But when I try to combine the two I can only search for managers that have an alias but not all managers do (I beleive this is a union query). the search boxes run off queries which are as follows;

Manager Names:

```
SELECT tblManagers.ManagerRef, tblManagers.[Manager Name]
FROM tblManagers
WHERE (((tblManagers.[Manager Name]) Like "*" & [forms]![frmManagerSelector]![txtSearchBox] & "*"))
ORDER BY tblManagers.[Manager Name];
```

Alias Names:

```
SELECT tblOldAliases.AliasRef, tblOldAliases.ManagerRef, tblOldAliases.[Previous Company Name], tblOldAliases.Notes
FROM tblManagers INNER JOIN tblOldAliases ON tblManagers.ManagerRef = tblOldAliases.ManagerRef
WHERE (((tblOldAliases.[Previous Company Name]) Like "*" & [forms]![frmManagerSelector]![txtAliasSearchBox] & "*"));
```

And the search boxes function like so;

```
Private Sub txtManagerList_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmManagerDetails", acNormal, "", "[ManagerRef]=" & Me.txtManagerList, , acNormal

End Sub

Private Sub txtSearchBox_Change()

Me.txtManagerList.SetFocus
Me.txtSearchBox.SetFocus
Me.txtManagerList.Requery

End Sub
```

The Alias search box works identically with different names.

Many thanks for any help in advance!

Nathanael

Comment: SELECT tblOldAliases.AliasRef, tblOldAliases.ManagerRef, tblOldAliases.[Previous Company Name], tblOldAliases.Notes
FROM tblManagers INNER JOIN tblOldAliases ON tblManagers.ManagerRef = tblOldAliases.ManagerRef
WHERE (((tblOldAliases.[Previous Company Name]) Like "*" & [forms]![frmManagerSelector]![txtAliasSearchBox] & "*")OR (((tblManagers.[Manager Name]) Like "*" & [forms]![frmManagerSelector]![txtAliasSearchBox] & "*")));

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this but it's now outputting no results?

Comment: Change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN - that would display members that have no aliases as well

Comment: Hi, I'm really sorry but this
SELECT tblOldAliases.AliasRef, tblOldAliases.ManagerRef, tblOldAliases.[Previous Company Name], tblManagers.[Manager Name]
FROM tblManagers LEFT JOIN tblOldAliases ON tblManagers.ManagerRef=tblOldAliases.ManagerRef
WHERE (((tblOldAliases.[Previous Company Name]) Like "" & forms!frmManagerSelector!txtSearchBox & "")) Or (((tblManagers.[Manager Name]) Like "" & forms!frmManagerSelector!txtSearchBox & ""));
Is still not outputting any results but I have no idea why

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and expect output as text tables.

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis first comment is an answer!

Comment: @NathanaelMatthews Vytautas sql code doesn't use wildcards(*)! It will only find exact matches. Just add wildcards in font and after the searchbox vars like you did in question.